# Python - how to create object or call method from class with kwargs

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have the following parent class with kwargs init:

```
class A(object):
    """ Parent class """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):     

        # connect parameters
        self.host           = kwargs.get('host', 'localhost')
        self.user           = kwargs.get('user', None)
        self.password       = kwargs.get('password', None)

    def connect(self):
        try:           
            self.ConnectWithCred( self.host, 
                                  self.port, 
                                  self.user,
                                  self.password)
        except pythoncom.com_error as error:
            e = format_com_message("Failed to connect")
            raise Error(e)
```

I want to create an object of 'class A' and call the 'connect' method.  How do I go about?  I tried the following and it wouldn't run (fyi - I'm a Python newbie):

```
sub_B = A(self.host = 'example.com', self.port = 22, self.user = 'root', 
          self.password = 'testing')
sub_B.connect()
```

Comment: Where’s your subclass?

Comment: I tried defining it like this:

Comment: Please edit that into your question.

Comment: sub_B = A(self.host = 'example.com', self.port = 22, self.user = 'root', 
          self.password = 'testing')
sub_B.connect()

Comment: That’s not a subclass. Do you mean you want to create an instance? Remove the `self.` in the kwargs you’re passing, and make `A`’s `__init__` accept a `port`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating an instance of `A`, not a subclass. Your problem is that your instantiation is a little incorrect, although close.

Remove `self` from the keyword arguments:

```
sub_B = A(host = 'example.com', port = 22, user = 'root', password = 'testing')
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Ah yes, that is working for me now, thank you so much!  Sorry for not posting the question correctly.